# Set color by condition in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I set a color by condition eg:

In my table there is a column called STATUS where receive the result from db.
with three texts: PG, PEN, ATR.

If status is PG, then color green, PEN color red etc..

How to do that?

My current code is `<th width="4%" scope="col"><?php echo $status;?></th>`

Comment: <th width="4%" scope="col"><?php echo $status;?></th>

Comment: Thank you guys, this solved my question.
This forum is the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a class on your HTML display, you could even make it `class="PG"` for example in case you decide to change the color of it later. Then you define the color of that class in css.

Using the example code you provided:

```
<th width="4%" scope="col" class="<?php echo $status;?>"> <?php echo $status;?></th>
```

CSS file would include:

```
.PG {text-color:green;} 
.PEN {text-color:red;}
```

Note: not sure if by color you meant background-color or text-color; either works.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I mean text-color.

Comment: Hi Chris, I use your code and this really solved my question. Thank you very much for help me. Now clarify how it work? class="<?php echo $status;?> Just to understand. echo name of self variable? Work very good!

Comment: Like I said in my text above, it just generates `class="PG"` or `class="PEN"`, whatever the value of $status is.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways you can do it (and probably a few others as well), but here are my three ways: set the value of the style, rewire the entire text, or inline php color setting... Here are the three ways below, from the best to worst, in my opinion.

**Set Value of the style method**

```
$style = '';

if ( $status == 'PG' )
    $style = 'style="color: green;"'; // You can replace with class=""
else if ( $status == 'PEN' )
    $style = 'style="color: red;"'; // You can replace with class=""
else if ( $status == 'ART')
    $style = 'style="color: blue;"'; // You can replace with class=""

?>

<th width="4%" scope="col" <?=$style?> ><?=$status?></th>
```

**Rewrite entire line method**

```
<?php

if ( $status == 'PG' )
    echo '<th width="4%" scope="col" style="color: green;">'.$status.'</th>';
else if ( $status == 'PEN' )
    echo '<th width="4%" scope="col" style="color: red;">'.$status.'</th>';
else if ( $status == 'ART' )
    echo '<th width="4%" scope="col" style="color: blue;">'.$status.'</th>';

?>
```

**Inline editing**

```
echo '<th width="4%" scope="col" ';

if ( $status == 'PG' )
    echo 'style="color: green;"';
else if ( $status == 'PEN' )
    echo 'style="color: red;"';
else if ( $status == 'ART' )
    echo 'style="color: blue;"';

echo '>'.$status.'</th>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set color in an array and you can assign them easily as below.

```
 $color = array (
        "PG"=>"green", // use color code here
        "PEN"=>"red"
       );
```

In html, you call the status color from array:

```
<tr style='background-color:<?php echo $color[$row["status"]];?>'>
<td>....</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are trying to set background color on based of $status...try this.

```
<?php 
If($status=='pg'){
      $color='red';
 }
elseif($status=='pen')
{
     $color='green';
}
elseif($status=='atr')
{
      $color='yellow';
 }
?>
<th width="4%" scope="col" style="background-color:<?php echo $color;?>">
    <?php echo $status;?>
</th>
```